# writing a bash script that uses sudo

Tags: command-line, scripts, sudo, su

I am sure that this is a very basic question but I'm afraid that I have been unable to get it to work or understand what is going on.

I have a node project that I usually run with

```
sudo npm start
```

and I am trying to create a bash script that will launch this for me.

I have tried a few variations:

```
su myname -c "npm run start"
sudo su myname -c "npm run start"
su myname -c "sudo npm start"
```

but they all seem to execute the command without superuser rights. From the research that I have done it seems that

```
sudo su myname -c "npm run start"
```

is the correct one but it doesn't work (it runs but without permissions).
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just `sudo npm start`? Why do you think you need anything else?

Comment: Do you want to run `npm start` as `root` or as `myname`? (To confuse you even more: there's also `sudo -u myname npm start` ;-))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use plain `sudo` in scripts, run the whole script with root permissions instead and use `sudo -u YOURUSERNAME` to execute commands *without* root permissions if that's really necessary.

Write a script like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
npm start
```

Save it, make it executable with `chmod +x /path/to/script` and start it with root permissions with:

```bsh
sudo /path/to/script    # from a terminal
gksudo /path/to/script  # without terminal (e.g. for a starter)
kdesudo /path/to/script # without terminal, KDE equivalent
```

That's all what it takes.

You may add further commands to the script, you could for example check whether it was started as root and exit else (thanks to [PerlDuck](https://askubuntu.com/users/504066/perlduck)):

```bsh
[[ $EUID -ne 0 ]] && echo "This script must be run as root." && exit 1
```

Comment: This will run the whole script as `root`. Not sure whether that's what the OP intended (in case it contains more commands than just `npm start`). The other way would be to run the script as `myname` and put `sudo npm start` _into_ the script. We don't know.

Comment: I often add code like `if [ 0 != $(id -u) ]; then echo "this script must be run as root"; exit 1; fi` or something similar to scripts when its crucial who runs them.

Comment: @PerlDuck Thanks, I did some edits. Even if only one command needs root permissions the whole script should still be run as root IMO.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a personal habit because I often have scripts that _must_ or _must not_ be run as root (or some other dedicated user) and they often show weird behaviour when started by someone else.

Comment: Re _"Even if only one command needs root permissions…"_: I decide that case by case. Sometimes I add an entry to `/etc/sudoers` for the _special command_ and run the script as `myname`. It just depends, I think.